# Oracle Designer wants the OCI.dll

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, designer

I have a problem with the Oracle Designer 10g which I have downloaded recently. The problem is that the program is missing the OCI.dll file. Due to this file I can't open it the program.
How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html) to an oracle client that will install an OCI.dll on your windows system.

The other thing to check before you do this is to ensure that the Windows environment variable include a path to the oracle bin folder

Running echo $PATH from the command line will show all the existing variables.  If you do not see a path to an Oracle Bin folder then you need to add the path if it exists or install the client